# end.date in RGoogleAnalytics query handles 'today()' as numeric?

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny, google-analytics-api

So I'd like to automate querying data with `RGoogleAnalytics` in a Shiny dashboard, instead of manually updating the dates in `server.R`. However, if I do this:

```
start.date <- "2015-02-10"
end.date <- today()-1
```

And then query using the above:

```
 query.list <- Init(start.date = start.date,
               end.date = end.date,
               dimensions = "ga:deviceCategory,ga:channelGrouping",
               metrics="ga:sessions",
               max.results = 50000,
               sort = "ga:channelGrouping",
               table.id = table.id)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : 
  code : 400 Reason : Invalid value '16656'. Values must match the following
  regular expression: '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo)'
```

Why doesn't the query recognize `end.date` as a Date object?

Comment: In your title, you speak about `start.date`, but in your code, you use `today()` to create `end.date`. Also, if you compare `class(start.date)` and `class(end.date)`, the former is `character`, when the latter is `Date`. Your problem is either the class of `start.date` or the class of `end.date`.

Comment: Check this out to format end.date like start.date: http://statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to store the end date as a character.

```
end.date <- as.character(today() - 1)
```